# How to merge mutliple CSV files into one with newline after each dataset

Tags: c#, csv, merge, csvhelper

I wrote a method which creates a list of strings. The string's values are accountance data. 
When I click on a button, a new .csv-file will be created.
It looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, there is no newline carriage return feed at the end of the line.
I would like to combine all of these .csv files to 1, each dataset for 1 row.
I tried that manually with this simple cmd copy command `copy *.csv allcsv.csv` but they are all appended in the first row instead of added to the next row:

[image]

1. What do I need to add/change in my code to include the newline character at the end of each row?
2. How could I include the cmd copy command in my method the easiest way possible?

   ```
           private void BuchungssatzBilden(object obj)
           {
           //Lieferschein-Buchungswerte in Liste speichern
           List<string> bs = new List<string>();
           bs.Add(SelItem.Umsatz.ToString());
           bs.Add(SelItem.Gegenkonto);
           bs.Add(SelItem.Beleg);
           bs.Add(SelItem.Buchungsdatum);
           bs.Add(SelItem.Konto);
           bs.Add(SelItem.Kost1);
           bs.Add(SelItem.Kost2);
           bs.Add(SelItem.Text);

           using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
           using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
           using (var sr = new StreamWriter(@"C:\" + SelItem.Beleg + SelItem.Text + SelItem.Hv + ".csv", true, Encoding.UTF8))
           {
               using (var csv = new CsvWriter(sr, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
               {

                   //csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";                    
                   //csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;


                   foreach (var s in bs)
                   {
                       csv.WriteField(s);   
                   }

                   csv.Flush();                    
                   stream.Position = 0;
                   reader.ReadToEnd();                  
               }
           }
           MessageBox.Show("CSV erfolgreich erstellt!");
       }
   ```

Comment: `sr.WriteLine()` after all the writes. Must be before `stream.Position=0;`

Comment: Anyway, what you should do is create a List with your class type, and generate the csv, not line by line, [like this](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started#writing-a-csv-file)

Comment: I agree with @Magnetron.  Is there a reason you can't use a list of your `SelItem` and pass that to `CsvWriter`?  `List<SelItem> records;` followed by `csv.WriteRecords(records);`

Comment: FWIW, [SoftCircuits.CsvParser](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SoftCircuits.CsvParser/) is about four times faster than CsvHelper.